# Android Old Browser not Deeplinking mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, browser, deep-linking

I have a mobile app which is available for Android and IPhone. For this i have a website where I have a javascript method which checks whether the user is accessing the website from mobile device or other. If it's a mobile device, i'm invoking my installed mobile app, if it's not installed or if it's not a mobile device, I redirect to the appropriate application store (This is done by two buttons, one for android and one for iPhone, onclick I call this method). I have added the method below

```
function redirectToApplication(appStoreUrl,mobileAppInvokeUrl){
 setTimeout(function () { window.location = appStoreUrl; }, 15);
 if(isMobile()){
    window.location = mobileAppInvokeUrl;
 }

}
```

My mobileApp Invoke Url looks something like this

```
myapp://app
```

This seems to be working fine for IPhone. In android it works fine for Chrome, Firefox and Opera. But this application does not seems to be working in the android default browser application (Which is named browser. This is not Chrome). In that application it tries to go to "http://myapp://app" and says page could not be found. I cannot find a solution for this problem because I cannot find the reason for this issue.

The identifier of this browser is provided below

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android x.x; Build/xx)
AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari 530/17
```

Is this a common problem and is there any solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Full disclosure, I'm currently an engineer at Branch)

Hey Visahan,

This is something [Branch links](http://branch.io?bmp=stackoverflow) do for you. We do exactly what you have built out, which means our links upon clicking take a user to your application if that user has your application already, or they take them to the respective app stores if they don't.

We basically format an intent string and set the document.location variable inside the browser to deliver a user to their app.

Specifically, we do something like this whenever someone hits our client side JS on Android:

```
var intentString = "intent://" + a + "#Intent;scheme=" + b.substring(0, b.length - 3) + ";package=";
if (!e || !e.length) {
    // id is package name of your Android app
    intentString = intentString + d.substring(d.indexOf('?id=') + 4, d.length) + ";";
} else {
    intentString = intentString + e + ";";
}
if (f && f.length) {
    // fallback URL incase app isn't on phone
    intentString = intentString + "S.browser_fallback_url=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + ";";
}
intentString = intentString + "end";
document.location = intentString;
```

This allows us to create an intent string for the specified browsers, since they follow an intent string model. We of course have a bit of custom logic with certain user agents and browsers but this is the gist of it.